# Simple update to working Twitter API Script

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using this bit of code to display tweets, everything is working fine but I would like to modify the script so that I can have a number next to each tweet. 
So it could look like:

```
Tweet 1
...first tweet goes here...

Tweet 2
...second tweet goes here...

...and so on...
```

I can't see anything obvious in the code to change or where to add:

```
<?php

    // Session start
    session_start(); 

    // Set timezone. (Modify to match your timezone) If you need help with this, you can find it here. (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    // Require TwitterOAuth files. (Downloadable from : https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)
    require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");

    // Function to authenticate app with Twitter.
    function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
      $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
      return $connection;
    }

    // Function to display the latest tweets.
    function display_latest_tweets(

        // Function parameters.
        $twitter_user_id,
        $cache_file          = './tweets.txt',  // Change this to the path of your cache file. (Default : ./tweets.txt)
        $tweets_to_display   = 5,               // Number of tweets you would like to display. (Default : 5)
        $ignore_replies      = false,           // Ignore replies from the timeline. (Default : false)
        $include_rts         = false,           // Include retweets. (Default : false)
        $twitter_wrap_open   = '<ul class="home-tweets-ul">',
        $twitter_wrap_close  = '</ul>',
        $tweet_wrap_open     = '<li><p class="home-tweet-tweet">',
        $meta_wrap_open      = '<br/><span class="home-tweet-date">',
        $meta_wrap_close     = '</span>',
        $tweet_wrap_close    = '</p></li>',
        $date_format         = 'g:i A M jS',    // Date formatting. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
        $twitter_style_dates = true){           // Twitter style days. [about an hour ago] (Default : true)

        // Twitter keys (You'lll need to visit https://dev.twitter.com and register to get these.
        $consumerkey         = "";
        $consumersecret      = "";
        $accesstoken         = "";
        $accesstokensecret   = "";

        // Seconds to cache feed (Default : 1 minute).
        $cachetime           = 60*3;

        // Time that the cache was last updtaed.
        $cache_file_created  = ((file_exists($cache_file))) ? filemtime($cache_file) : 0;

        // A flag so we know if the feed was successfully parsed.
        $tweet_found         = false;

        // Show cached version of tweets, if it's less than $cachetime.
        if (time() - $cachetime < $cache_file_created) {
            $tweet_found = true;
            // Display tweets from the cache.
            readfile($cache_file);       
        } else {

        // Cache file not found, or old. Authenticae app.
        $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

            if($connection){
                // Get the latest tweets from Twitter
                $get_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitter_user_id."&count=".$tweets_to_display."&include_rts=".$include_rts);

                // Error check: Make sure there is at least one item.
                if (count($get_tweets)) {

                    // Define tweet_count as zero
                    $tweet_count = 0;

                    // Start output buffering.
                    ob_start();

                    // Open the twitter wrapping element.
                    $twitter_html = $twitter_wrap_open;

                    // Iterate over tweets.
                    foreach($get_tweets as $tweet) {

                        // If we are not ignoring replies, or tweet is not a reply, process it.
                        if ($ignore_replies==false){

                            $tweet_found = true;
                            $tweet_count++;
                            $tweet_desc = $tweet->text;
                            // Add hyperlink html tags to any urls, twitter ids or hashtags in the tweet.
                            $tweet_desc = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+)/','<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',$tweet_desc);
                            $tweet_desc = preg_replace('/(^|[\n\s])@([^\s"\t\n\r<:]*)/is', '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>', $tweet_desc);
                            $tweet_desc = preg_replace('/(^|[\n\s])#([^\s"\t\n\r<:]*)/is', '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">#$2</a>', $tweet_desc);

                            // Convert Tweet display time to a UNIX timestamp. Twitter timestamps are in UTC/GMT time.
                            $tweet_time = strtotime($tweet->created_at);    
                            if ($twitter_style_dates){
                                // Current UNIX timestamp.
                                $current_time = time();
                                $time_diff = abs($current_time - $tweet_time);
                                switch ($time_diff) 
                                {
                                    case ($time_diff < 60):
                                        $display_time = $time_diff.' seconds ago';                  
                                        break;      
                                    case ($time_diff >= 60 && $time_diff < 3600):
                                        $min = floor($time_diff/60);
                                        $display_time = $min.' minutes ago';                  
                                        break;      
                                    case ($time_diff >= 3600 && $time_diff < 86400):
                                        $hour = floor($time_diff/3600);
                                        $display_time = 'about '.$hour.' hour';
                                        if ($hour > 1){ $display_time .= 's'; }
                                        $display_time .= ' ago';
                                        break;          
                                    default:
                                        $display_time = date($date_format,$tweet_time);
                                        break;
                                }
                            } else {
                                $display_time = date($date_format,$tweet_time);
                            }

                            // Render the tweet.
                            $twitter_html .= $tweet_wrap_open.html_entity_decode($tweet_desc).$meta_wrap_open.'<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$twitter_user_id.'">'.$display_time.'</a>'.$meta_wrap_close.$tweet_wrap_close;

                        }

                        // If we have processed enough tweets, stop.
                        if ($tweet_count >= $tweets_to_display){
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    // Close the twitter wrapping element.
                    $twitter_html .= $twitter_wrap_close;
                    echo $twitter_html;

                    // Generate a new cache file.
                    $file = fopen($cache_file, 'w');

                    // Save the contents of output buffer to the file, and flush the buffer. 
                    fwrite($file, ob_get_contents()); 
                    fclose($file); 
                    ob_end_flush();

                }

            }

        }

    }

    // Display latest tweets. (Modify username to your Twitter handle)
    display_latest_tweets('');
     ?>
```

Many thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question right you want a simple counter in your Tweet displaying loop, I have amended the source code below with the following lines;

```
// Set counter to zero
$Counter = 0;

// Iterate over tweets.
foreach($get_tweets as $tweet) {

    // Increment counter 
    $Counter += 1;

    // Display counter
    echo 'Tweet ',$Counter;
```

Hope this helps!

```
    <?php
        // Session start
        session_start(); 

        // Set timezone. (Modify to match your timezone) If you need help with this, you can find it here. (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

        // Require TwitterOAuth files. (Downloadable from : https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)
        require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");

        // Function to authenticate app with Twitter.
        function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
          $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
          return $connection;
        }

        // Function to display the latest tweets.
        function display_latest_tweets(

            // Function parameters.
            $twitter_user_id,
            $cache_file          = './tweets.txt',  // Change this to the path of your cache file. (Default : ./tweets.txt)
            $tweets_to_display   = 5,               // Number of tweets you would like to display. (Default : 5)
            $ignore_replies      = false,           // Ignore replies from the timeline. (Default : false)
            $include_rts         = false,           // Include retweets. (Default : false)
            $twitter_wrap_open   = '<ul class="home-tweets-ul">',
            $twitter_wrap_close  = '</ul>',
            $tweet_wrap_open     = '<li><p class="home-tweet-tweet">',
            $meta_wrap_open      = '<br/><span class="home-tweet-date">',
            $meta_wrap_close     = '</span>',
            $tweet_wrap_close    = '</p></li>',
            $date_format         = 'g:i A M jS',    // Date formatting. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
            $twitter_style_dates = true){           // Twitter style days. [about an hour ago] (Default : true)

            // Twitter keys (You'lll need to visit https://dev.twitter.com and register to get these.
            $consumerkey         = "";
            $consumersecret      = "";
            $accesstoken         = "";
            $accesstokensecret   = "";

            // Seconds to cache feed (Default : 1 minute).
            $cachetime           = 60*3;

            // Time that the cache was last updtaed.
            $cache_file_created  = ((file_exists($cache_file))) ? filemtime($cache_file) : 0;

            // A flag so we know if the feed was successfully parsed.
            $tweet_found         = false;

            // Show cached version of tweets, if it's less than $cachetime.
            if (time() - $cachetime < $cache_file_created) {
                $tweet_found = true;
                // Display tweets from the cache.
                readfile($cache_file);       
            } else {

            // Cache file not found, or old. Authenticae app.
            $connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

                if($connection){
                    // Get the latest tweets from Twitter
                    $get_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitter_user_id."&count=".$tweets_to_display."&include_rts=".$include_rts);

                    // Error check: Make sure there is at least one item.
                    if (count($get_tweets)) {

                        // Define tweet_count as zero
                        $tweet_count = 0;

                        // Start output buffering.
                        ob_start();

                        // Open the twitter wrapping element.
                        $twitter_html = $twitter_wrap_open;

                        // Set counter to zero
                        $Counter = 0;

                        // Iterate over tweets.
                        foreach($get_tweets as $tweet) {
                            // Increment counter 
                            $Counter += 1;

                            // Display counter
                            echo 'Tweet ',$Counter;

                            // If we are not ignoring replies, or tweet is not a reply, process it.
                            if ($ignore_replies==false){

                                $tweet_found = true;
                                $tweet_count++;
                                $tweet_desc = $tweet->text;
                                // Add hyperlink html tags to any urls, twitter ids or hashtags in the tweet.
                                $tweet_desc = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+)/','<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',$tweet_desc);
                                $tweet_desc = preg_replace('/(^|[\n\s])@([^\s"\t\n\r<:]*)/is', '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>', $tweet_desc);
                                $tweet_desc = preg_replace('/(^|[\n\s])#([^\s"\t\n\r<:]*)/is', '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">#$2</a>', $tweet_desc);

                                // Convert Tweet display time to a UNIX timestamp. Twitter timestamps are in UTC/GMT time.
                                $tweet_time = strtotime($tweet->created_at);    
                                if ($twitter_style_dates){
                                    // Current UNIX timestamp.
                                    $current_time = time();
                                    $time_diff = abs($current_time - $tweet_time);
                                    switch ($time_diff) 
                                    {
                                        case ($time_diff < 60):
                                            $display_time = $time_diff.' seconds ago';                  
                                            break;      
                                        case ($time_diff >= 60 && $time_diff < 3600):
                                            $min = floor($time_diff/60);
                                            $display_time = $min.' minutes ago';                  
                                            break;      
                                        case ($time_diff >= 3600 && $time_diff < 86400):
                                            $hour = floor($time_diff/3600);
                                            $display_time = 'about '.$hour.' hour';
                                            if ($hour > 1){ $display_time .= 's'; }
                                            $display_time .= ' ago';
                                            break;          
                                        default:
                                            $display_time = date($date_format,$tweet_time);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $display_time = date($date_format,$tweet_time);
                                }

                                // Render the tweet.
                                $twitter_html .= $tweet_wrap_open.html_entity_decode($tweet_desc).$meta_wrap_open.'<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$twitter_user_id.'">'.$display_time.'</a>'.$meta_wrap_close.$tweet_wrap_close;

                            }

                            // If we have processed enough tweets, stop.
                            if ($tweet_count >= $tweets_to_display){
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        // Close the twitter wrapping element.
                        $twitter_html .= $twitter_wrap_close;
                        echo $twitter_html;

                        // Generate a new cache file.
                        $file = fopen($cache_file, 'w');

                        // Save the contents of output buffer to the file, and flush the buffer. 
                        fwrite($file, ob_get_contents()); 
                        fclose($file); 
                        ob_end_flush();

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        // Display latest tweets. (Modify username to your Twitter handle)
        display_latest_tweets('');
    ?>
```

Comment: Cool - will try out right now - thank you for the speedy & detailed response.

Comment: Unfortunately, my output is 'Tweet 1 Tweet 1 Tweet 1' where it should be 'Tweet 1 Tweet 2 Tweet 3'. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Sorry about that, maybe try `$Counter++;` ?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Ah I see my mistake now, I have updated the code to fix the problem. Please try again :)